# RewriteRule & Header set Expires : how to

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using rewrite rules to create a /fr /en on my website and does folder don't exist, therefore if I try to use

```
<Directory /fr>
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
</Directory>
```

Apache complain because the folder does not exist, can't find a way to do it in the http.conf

If I use

```
Header set Expires "access plus 1 day"
```

in the .htaccess, can see the header showing

```
Expires: access plus 1 day
```

instead of the date + 1 day, if i remove it I can see

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

Also if I use

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
```

It does not work...

Can you please tell how to get this right?

Also I believe that Safari (and only safari) keep on reloading the page every minutes because of that, is that correct or just another issue?

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Directory instructions are working on real filesystem paths. So a Directory setting should looks like :

```
<Directory /var/www/foo/bar/fr >
    (...)
</Directory>
```

Instead, if you prefer working with url path you must use Location directives:

```
<Location /fr >
    (...)
</Location>
```

This should at least fix your inexistents directories problems (if I understand your first sentence, which is quite strange)

Comment: All the content is dynamically generated and there is /fr or /en , simply using mode rewrite to create nice url and this bit works fine. When try to add <Location /fr>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault A300
</Location> I still have the header saying : Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT